# How to play Video from application cache in android

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

I want to play video file from android cache folder using the following code :

```
String cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
File outFile = new File(cacheDir, "intro.mp4");
vvIntro.setVideoPath(cacheDir+"/intro");
vvIntro.start();
```

But I got error :

```
07-05 20:14:21.896: E/MediaPlayer(1251): error (1, -2147483648)
07-05 20:14:21.928: I/Choreographer(1251): Skipped 79 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-05 20:14:22.186: D/gralloc_goldfish(1251): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-05 20:14:22.496: E/MediaPlayer(1251): Error (1,-2147483648)
07-05 20:14:22.496: D/VideoView(1251): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

where the file is already exists and the required persimmon as show below :
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a `File` object pointing to your MP4 file, then totally ignore that `File` object and provide an invalid path to `vvIntro`. Instead, try:

```
File outFile = new File(getCacheDir(), "yourVideoName.mp4");
vvIntro.setVideoPath(outFile.getAbsolutePath());
vvIntro.start();
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: in this case,  If I play the video from a uri from a server in listview, then what to do ?

Comment: @NoorHossain: This question and answer are nine years old at this point. I recommend ExoPlayer over `VideoView`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. And for that reason I actually like you from my heart, Thanks. Any example link for exoplayer with seek bar ?

Comment: @NoorHossain: I do not have one, but a *lot* has been written about ExoPlayer, and IIRC the time bar comes by default with a basic ExoPlayer setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use my simple library [AndroidVideoCache](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache). It allows stream and cache video simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

you can set Uri :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir()+"/video.mp4") ;
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.start();
```